# removing inline styles from wp-caption div

Tags: posts, images

Inline width and height attributes were never a huge problem with images in WordPress, since these were easily overwritten with CSS.

The problem I'm having is that any images with captions are being wrapped in a ID 'attachment_('attachmentnumber') and a class of 'wp-caption' AND they're given inline CSS width and height properties.
This is a major pain in the butt, so I'd like to remove the inline styles of this div if at all possible.

Comment: I looked for a solution to this a well and found Joots Kiens' implementation to be better. info about the implementation from http://joostkiens.com/improving-wp-caption-shortcode/. Source at Github: https://gist.github.com/JoostKiens/4477366

Answer (score 9):

To remove the inline width in a clean PHP-way could be done with a filter, as described in the source code: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/media.php#L1587

Returning a zero (or false) will remove it:

```
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode_width', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Still worked like a charm in 2024. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

You can override inline styles with "!important" like this:

```
width: 100px !important;
```

If you want a PHP fix take a look at this:
http://troychaplin.ca/2012/06/updated-function-fix-inline-style-that-added-image-caption-wordpress-3-4/

```
add_shortcode('wp_caption', 'fixed_img_caption_shortcode');
add_shortcode('caption', 'fixed_img_caption_shortcode');
function fixed_img_caption_shortcode($attr, $content = null) {
    if ( ! isset( $attr['caption'] ) ) {
        if ( preg_match( '#((?:<a [^>]+>\s*)?<img [^>]+>(?:\s*</a>)?)(.*)#is', $content, $matches ) ) {
        $content = $matches[1];
        $attr['caption'] = trim( $matches[2] );
        }
    }

    $output = apply_filters('img_caption_shortcode', '', $attr, $content);
    if ( $output != '' )
    return $output;

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => '',
        'align' => 'alignnone',
        'width' => '',
        'caption' => ''
    ), $attr));

    if ( 1 > (int) $width || empty($caption) )
    return $content;

    if ( $id ) $id = 'id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" ';

    return '<div ' . $id . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr($align) . '" style="width: ' . $width . 'px">' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '<p>' . $caption . '</p></div>';
}
```

or javascript/JQuery:

```
$(".wp-caption").removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: !important has always been supported, that part can be edited out. If you could also take the PHP solution and put it in your answer? At the moment if troychaplin.ca goes down this answer becomes useless